# How to use "sed" in a single column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, multiple-columns

I would like to replace a string with another string in a single column.

Input:

```
A.a     1
A.b     .
A.c     1
A.d     1
```

Desired output:

```
A.a     1
A.b     -9
A.c     1
A.d     1
```

Using `sed 's/\./-9/g' input > output` it modifies all `.` by `-9`, and this is what I obtain:

```
A-9a     1
A-9b     -9
A-9c     1
A-9d     1
```

How can I use `sed` on a single column ($2) only?

Comment: If it really has to be in sed, you can say `sed '2s/\.$/-9/' file`, using the fact that it is the 2nd line.

Comment: you can try sed 's/\./-9/2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==2{$2="-9"} 1' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

Above will simply change `$2` value to `-9` in case you need to cross verify that 2nd line's 2nd field is a `.` and you want to do change then only then following may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==2 && $2=="."{$2="-9"} 1' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '$2=="."{$2="-9"} 1' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

Append `> temp_file &&  mv temp_file  Input_file` to get the output in Input_file itself.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly fine. 
And if I want to apply it on the entire column (not only line 2) I can use: `awk 'FNR==NR{$2="-9"} 1' OFS="\t"   Input_file`

Comment: Then use `gsub(/\./,"-9")` instead of `$2="-9"` in code, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: (a) `awk 'FNR==NR{gsub(/\./,"-9")} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file ` replaces the `.` both in column 1 and column 2, and not only in column 2; while (b)  `awk 'FNR==2{gsub(/\./,"-9")} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file` applies on the entire second line and not the second column.

Comment: use `gsub(/\./,"-9",$1)` for first field `gsub(/\./,"-9",$2)` for second field, let me know how it works?

Comment: `awk 'FNR==2{gsub(/\./,"-9",$2)} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file` does not work but `awk 'FNR==NR{gsub(/\./,"-9",$2)} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file` works.

Comment: @Svalf, `FNR==NR` means it will be true for all lines for first file(in case you have mentioned multiple files) `FNR==2` will be true only for 2nd line of file.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry for that. The issue is that I was looking for something modifying entire 2nd column, not 2nd line.

Comment: @Svalf, could you please do let me know the reason for removing this as correct answer?

Comment: @EdMorton, sure, I think I had given 2nd Solution that only where it checks about if `$2` is a dot or not.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure added that solution too now.

Comment: @Svalf, please check my OR solution now.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I thought I was accepting it but since I had already accepted it as correct answer it removed it. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use group pattern. A bit heavy in sed but in this case it is still easy.

```
sed 's/^\([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+\)\./\1-9/' input > output

# a more generic for the 4th column (\{3\} here mean 3 group before)
sed 's/^\(\([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+\)\{3\}\)\./\1-9/' input > output
```

the last  `g` is not needed here because it only works for 1 element on a line